# can not set user write permissions to file in SMB mounted directory

Tags: mount, chmod, chown, smb

I have mounted a Windows 10 directory so I can edit some files on my Windownz machine.

`sudo mount -t cifds //W10/Users ~/public/ -o username=bobby`

When checking the directories they all have the owner `root` and as user `bobby` I only have read permission.

I already used `chown` and `chmod` to change the owner and permissions. The verbose output all told me that the owner was changed for instance but it was not. I was not able to edit files in there with user `bobby`.

What am I getting wrong in this case?

Answer (score 2):

Unix file systems and Windows file systems are different. You have to provide the owner with the `uid` option because the SMB client will not be able to extract an owner from the Windows file system. As the owner presented to the Linux programs doesn't exist, it's not possible to change the owner. This leaves two possibilities for system calls like `chown`.

- They can either return failure, because they can't succeed, but that would lead to many warning messages or even to programs the stop once they fail.
- Or they can pretend that they succeeded. Many programs operate smoothly thinking that everything worked as expected, but it can also be confusing when you expect the operation to actually succeed.

So you aren't doing anything wrong, the software doesn't support it.

You can use the `uid` and `gid` options to specify user and group for all files in the mounted file system. You can also use `file_mode` and `dir_mode` for the permissions of files and directories.

**Edit**

See `man mount.cifs`.

Exmaples:

- This will give read/write access to everybody. Use with caution.

  ```
  mount -t cifs //W10/Users ~/public/ -o username=bobb,dir_mode=777,file_mode=666
  ```
- This will mount the file system as `user` and `group`

  ```
  mount -t cifs //W10/Users ~/public/ -o username=bobb,uid=user,gid=group
  ```

Comment: Sorry I am not able to follow you with those `uid` and `gid` options. Which tool has those? `chown`,`mount` or `smbclient` ? Can you maybe provide a little example to give me a hint?

Comment: It's in `mount.cifs`, or `mount -t cifs`.